# Getting the nuget package information programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, specflow

How do I get the list of nuget packages in use within my project programmatically.

The information and versions are to be outputted to a log file.

I know how to get this information using the package manager, however I cannot get this information using code.

I am using specflow to write Unit Tests and would like this to be included in my log file.

Comment: You mention `specflow`. Are you looking to do this as part of a unit test (i.e., at design time), or after your app has been deployed?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Specflow.
It is part of a unit test.

Comment: You should be able to if you make an addin via Managed Package Framework

Comment: Then I would just read `packages.config`, or the `<PackageReference>` items in SDK projects. Note that the latter may not include transitive package references.

Answer (score 0):

If the packages.config-files are available where you run the unit tests, then I would also suggest to parse the packages.config files. They are strictly xml-based (see the according [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config)), so they can be read with any xml parser, for example by using XDocument:

```
  XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fileName);
  foreach (XElement packageNode in document.XPathSelectElements("/packages/package"))
  {
      string id = packageNode.Attribute("id").Value;
      string version = packageNode.Attribute("version").Value;
      ...
  }
```

From the id and the version (and the target framework if this is relevant for you) you can construct a set of used packages.